# Are there high quality alternatives to Sigma-Delta for Audio

Tags: adc

Is Sigma-delta pretty much the only game in town when it comes to ADC in the audio world (min 20-20k frequency response) ?

By looking at some of the major players and chip manufacturers like TI, Analog Devices, and few others, that certainly seems the case.

Looking for maximum performance--linearity, timing, F response,  S/N (if that is even a factor).

I think $100 max per stereo pair. That seems crazy given you can get a Burr-Brown Ti or others for under $30.

Comment: Please define "maximum performance". Linearity? Offset? Frequency response? Fast conversion? ...

Comment: SNR is amongst other things related to the number of bits. Maximum performance ... how much money do you want to throw at it? Instead of saying "maximum performance" you should be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not, it's the most common and probably cheapest, but you can find SAR (Edit: successive approximation) converters that are quite competitive (in performance) with very good Delta-Sigma converters.

Comment: Is there any compelling reason to use SAR?

Comment: I had to Google for [SAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_approximation_ADC) as I wasn't aware of the abbreviation.

Comment: Performance could well be better. Is performance your primary concern? No idle tones, perhaps.

Comment: SAR is potentially less sensitive to clock jitter, in addition to the idle tone issue.

Comment: When I was a young boy not all SAR converters had a sample and hold stage. Not sure what the playing field is like these days, but due to duration of the conversion you really want an S&H in (front of) the converter.